# How can I fix the error axios is undefined when using javascript

Tags: javascript, axios

I have installed axios using "npm install axios". When I try to pull the data from the API (which I have tested using postman, and it does exactly what is expected, I get an error in the console saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: axios is not defined"

This is the content of my .js file:

```
const spellInput = document.getElementById("Spell name");
const searchButton = document.getElementById("Search");
const spellOutput = document.getElementById("SpellOutput");

searchButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const spellName = spellInput.value.toLowerCase();
    if (spellName) {
        searchSpell(spellName);
    } else {
        spellOutput.innerHTML = "Please enter a spell name";
    }
});

function searchSpell(spellName) {
    axios
        .get(`https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/spells`)
        .then((response) => {
            const spells = response.data.results;
            const matchedSpell = spells.find((spell) => spell.name.toLowerCase() === spellName);
        
        if (matchedSpell) {
            axios
                .get(matchedSpell.url)
                .then((spellResponse) => {
                    const spellData = spellResponse.data;
                    spellOutput.innerHTML = `<p> ${spellData.name} </p>`;
                })
        }
        })
}
```

Comment: Where do you define it?  Did you forget to import or reference the Axios library in some way?

Comment: `npm` is for installing node.js libraries on the server. This is client code. You need to load Axios with a `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

just import axios

```
 import axios from 'axios';
```

Or if you're not using ES6 modules, you can include Axios using a script tag in your HTML file:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have tried using both of these - the import gives an error saying that it can't use import statements outside a module, and the script produces the original error.